# Can't run any .exe files

Tags: windows-vista

I had Windows Vista and it got a virus. I reinstalled the operating system but with XP. Now it works absolutely fine, but every time I try to open a .exe file, i'm told 'the filename directory name syntax is incorrect'

Answer (score 2):

I had a virus a few months ago and after I deleted the virus I couldn't run any exe files.  I thought this was a nice touch by the virus writer.  Anyway, there is a web site that has registry tweaks and one of the tweaks restores the ability to run exe files.  Sometimes a virus will also disable the ability to process registry files too but the site has instructions for fixing this.

http://www.dougknox.com/xp/file_assoc.htm

Look for:

(Restore default association for EXE files)

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you reinstalled the OS without removing the old one, thus corrupting the registry.  Since you just reinstalled, I suggest you back up your data, *format the hard disk*, then reinstall XP one more time.

Answer (score 0):

The registry might still be corrupted from the previous installation somehow.

`HKCR\exefile\shell\open\command` should have a default value of `"%1" %*`

If you can't run `regedit.exe`, try making a copy and renaming it to `regedit.com` or `regedit.bat`. File extensions don't matter for executable files.

Comment: Renaming it to `regedit.bat` will fail MISERABLY. It could, in theory corrupt your system ever further, as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 0):

See "Let me fix it myself"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950505

Or use this File Association fixer tool
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-windows-7-file-association/